# $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{n^{n-1}v^n}{n!}$ for what value of $v$ this series will be convergent? How to proceed for it?

Tags: convergence-divergence, lambert-w

I am interested in the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}v^{n} \right).$$ This series defines the tree function.

Comment: Is that $\;v^n\;$ in the numerator or in the denominator? Is $\;v\ge 0?\;$ Or $\;v\in\Bbb R\,,\,\Bbb C\ldots$ ?

Comment: Hint: $$|v| \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}\frac{n^{n - 1}}{(n + 1)^{(n + 1) - 1}}},$$

in order for the series to be convergent.

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 5):

Since $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n$, the convergence will be the same as $\sum \frac{e^n}{n\sqrt{2\pi n}} v^n$.  That is, we'll have convergence for $|v|\leq 1/e$.

Comment: Thank you-sir. Can you please explain it in detail? Also how to get the approximate value of $n!$ ?

Comment: @user3563283 That is Stirling's approximation.  The important thing here is that $n!$ sits between two constant multiples of that expression, so we can substitute without affecting convergence.  Were there any particular details you wanted?

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\exp{n}}{n*\sqrt{2*pi*n}}}v^{n} \right).$$ Can you please give details of the convergence of this series further?

Comment: @user3563283: For $v=1/e$, you are looking at $\sum \frac{n^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ which converges and clearly any smaller positive $v$ will do this too. For $v=k/e$ with $k \gt 1$, the individual terms  $k^n \frac{n^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ eventually increase almost exponentially and so the sum cannot converge.

Comment: @you-sir-33433: The value of $v$ is obtained simply by inspection or it is a guess. Is there some method/approach to obtain $v$ for the series to be convergent?

Comment: @user3563283 Henry gave an outline.  When $v\in (-1/e, 1/e)$, we have $|\sum_n \frac{e^n v^n}{n\sqrt{2\pi n}}| \leq \sum_n \frac{e^n |v|^n}{n\sqrt{2\pi n}} <\sum_n e^n |v|^n = \frac{e|v|}{1-e|v|}$, so the series converges.  For $v=-1/e$, it's an alternating series.  For $v=1/e$, we have to examine the convergence of $\sum n^{-3/2}$.  For any other $v$, the terms no longer approach $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$|v| \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}\frac{n^{n - 1}}{(n + 1)^{(n + 1) - 1}}\right)},$$

in order for the series to be convergent.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentionned $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}v^{n} \right)=-W(-v)$$ and you know that Euler and Lambert established that $W(x)$ is only defined for $x \geq - \frac{1}{e}$.